# Remove comma from a XML element in a file using UNIX commands

Tags: unix, replace

I have a file in UNIX system. It is a big file of about 100 MB. It is an XML file. There is a particular XML tag:

```
<XYZ> 5,434 </XYZ>
```

It contains a comma and I need to remove it.

How should I go about doing this using UNIX commands?

Comment: ya , sorry , the xml tag is suppose <ABC>5,434</ABC>, so its a big file containing XML tags like this , I have to search that XML tag and remove comma from the value. What could be the unix command for that.?

Comment: BTW, it turns out that the reason your question seemed ambiguous was formatting. If you just put bare `<XYZ>` tags in your question, they're treated like HTML and not rendered by the viewer's browser, unless you put them in a code-formatted block (indented with four spaces, which the `{}` button in the StackOverflow editor will do for you). This is why folks couldn't see the `XYZ` tags you put in your original question.

Comment: BTW, note that xmlstarlet -- like most command-line tools that are freely available -- uses libxslt to run the transform. Not the most memory-efficient thing in the world with large documents; if you're trying to do this on a very limited resource budget (in terms of virtual memory available), an implementation with a SAX-style processor may be more appropriate. I don't know of any of these in freely available command-line tools that are widely packaged, but it'd be easy to implement one in Python using lxml, which you could call from your shell scripts.

Comment: Anyhow, I'd suggest reporting back if you run out of memory using the answer given.

Comment: Terminology point: in XML, a _‘tag’_ is a start-tag or end-tag, such as `<XYZ>` or `</XYZ>`.  an _‘element’_ is the thing bracketed by start- and end-tags `<XYZ>...</XYZ>`, where the `...` may include other elements. Your question was initially perplexing because you had the terminology back to front. Thus a _tag_ which contains a comma can only mean something like `<X,Y>`.

Answer (score 1):

Using [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) to remove commas from text nodes associated with elements named `XYZ`:

```
xmlstarlet ed \
  -u "//XYZ[contains(., ',')]" \
  -x "translate(., ',', '')" \
  <input.xml >output.xml
```

The functions used here -- `contains()` and `translate()` -- are defined in the [XPath 1.0 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions).